$\psi,f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are continuous, $\psi=0$ outside $[0,1]$, $\int\psi=1$. $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^{100}f(x)\psi(nx)dx=?$
The Question
If $\psi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function $\ni$ $\int_{0}^{1}\psi(y)dy = 1$, $\psi(y) = 0$ when $y$ doesn't belong to $[0,1]$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a twice differentiable function Then, calculate the following limit.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^{100}f(x)\psi(nx)dx$$
My Attempt:
Firstly, I restricted the limits from $0$ to $\frac{1}{n}$ as $\psi(nx)$ is $0$ outside 1. Then I used L'Hôpital's rule, the above limit equals:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(\frac{1}{n})\psi(1)(n^{-2})-f(0)\psi(0)\cdot0}{-\frac{1}{n^{2}}}$  (using the formula of differentiating under integral sign) which yields $f(0)\psi(1)$. But the answer is expected to come only in terms of $f$ or $f^{'}$ on some point.
I tried By parts as well, but that didn't help as well. Kindly guide me here.

Given that the integral uses values of the function outside $[0,1],$ and the only condition is on the value in $[0,1],$ it seems unlikely this has a solution.

Are you sure your question is correct? imagine $\psi$ being a constant function, being equal to $1$. Then that integral can be anything, and by multiplying it by $n$ and letting that $n$ go to infinity, you end up with $+\infty$. Or am I missing something?

Why would $\psi(nx)$ be $0$ outside $[0;1]$ ?!

I am really sorry for the trouble caused. I missed one line $\psi(x) = 0$ outside $[0,1]$. Consider my sincerest apology.

@Dominique you are right. I missed one condition, I added it.

@AnneBauval how do you get that? I am not able to get rid of $g(1)$ in my case.

I have some more remarks, but as I need an image to explain, I've written an answer for that.

@AnneBauval I didn't understand two things: 1.) How is f uniformly continuous and more than that 2.) If we assume f to be uniformly continuous, how is the last step utilize it. Is the product of two uniformly continuous function uniformly continuous? If so is the case, then I guess we can interchange the integration and limit. Could you clarify a bit.


https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3228511/timeline#comment_10476510 2) $\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\forall x<1/N,|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. With $|g|\le M$, this implies  $|\int_0^1 (f(\frac tn)-f(0))g(t) ,dt|\le M\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.


@AnneBauval Thanks a lot. I think I got it. Could you fix the link in your above comment

@AnneBauval Okay. I see. Yeah I managed to see your comment there. I finished the details of the solution as you pointed. Thanks a lot.
